# Why Windows 8 does not update disk space after I move 1 Gb to sd card

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive

I bought a 16Gb tablet. I moved OfficeOEM from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft to a sd card. Still disk space stays the same for C whereas size should have increased by 1 Gb.

When I look at disk size it's weird on 14 Gb only 5 Gb is llocated which should leave 10 Gb. In truth I have only 3.5 Gb instead of at least 4.5 Gb after moving some to sd card.

[image]

Comment: Any of the original items of the microsoft windows system, for the modern vista and up, what you see of the files in various folders is merly a hard link projection from the winsxs component store. If you grabbed and moved these files , The one link from the program data location would move the whole of the file data to the other location. .  Still in the original component store the items and data would exist.  While I do not know about Office oem ,  that is the way the rest of the items would also act, like players , viewers  any originating programs of the system, even pics and sounds.

Comment: I have already done so on other computers on windows 8 and it did increase disk space

Comment: For what items had you done this before? User items , user installed programs, and other stuff not part of the component store do not (nessiarily) have hard links.  There are hard link viewers available for the windows sytem that would show what is and what isnt using these methods.